# OpenLayers SelectFeature - Manually set feature as selected/unselected

Tags: openlayers-2

In the OpenLayers SelectFeature, how can I manually set a feature as selected/unselected and have it reflect the appropriate color?

For instance, when my application loads, it sends back the existing select state which I want to set on the polygons.

Comment: Use styleMap rules example http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/select-feature-multilayer.html

Comment: I'm unclear from the example on how to manually select a feature. Are you referring to using renderIntent to show the right colors initially? Will that also show the element as selected? I'm going to work on an example on JSFiddle and share it in a bit.

Comment: select an object it changes colour indicating it is selected.

Comment: jsfiddle is ideal.

Comment: I get that the color changes when you click and select the box. Question is how to manually trigger that. Almost done with the fiddle.

Comment: Figured it out. Posting an answer.

Comment: Since it won't let me post an answer for 8 hours, I need to wait before I can do that. However, the fiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/theoutlander/98337/. Using clickFeature(feature) or select(feature) allows us to manually select the feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that there are two methods which can be used to select a feature manually.

1. Method select(feature) in the [SelectFeatures](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/SelectFeature-js.html) control.
2. Method clickFeature(feature) in the SelectFeatures control.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/theoutlander/98337/) demonstrating that feature in case anyone else is interested.

At one point, I wasn't able to get select to work. Setting selectFeature.allowSelection to true let me select it, but later I noticed that it worked without it so I'm not sure when setting that to true is required. If you run into any issues, you might want to try playing with that attribute. Looking into the source further should allow us to understand the purpose of that variable.

Comment: Not allowed to post more than two links under 10 reputation so I had to remove references to select and clickFeature. However, they're available on the SelectFeatures control page link that I've included.